# Get bounds of untrimmed string

Tags: android, string, space, trim

In an App I am working on, I am trying to draw some text on a Canvas using a Paint. To do this, I use:

```
String string = " a ";
Rect bounds = new Rect();
mPaint.getTextBounds(string, 0, string.length(), bounds);
```

The thing is, this gives me the bounds of " a", not of " a ". It removes the space after the a, but I don't want it to do that.

Does anybody know how I can get the text bounds including the space after the letter?

**EDIT: **

I found a work around:

```
String string = " a ";
Rect bounds = new Rect();
mPaint.getTextBounds(string, 0, string.length(), bounds);
float width = mPaint.measureText(string);
float height = bounds.height();
RectF boundsF = new RectF(x, y, x + width, y + height);
```

The problem was that getTextBounds() is a native method that removes all trailing edge spaces. Paint.measureText(String string) doesn't do this, so we can use this width.

Comment: have you tried temporarily replacing the " " characters with something else, like "_" (underscore)

Comment: Yes, and it shows the underscores if I do :)

Answer (score 0):

from doc

Parameters:
text String to measure and return its bounds

start Index of the first char in the string to measure

end **1** past the last char in the string measure

bounds Returns the unioned bounds of all the text. Must be allocated by the caller.

[Ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)

so i think you need to call,

```
mPaint.getTextBounds(string, 0, string.length()+1, bounds);
```

Comment: No, string.length() + 1 is too long (gives an Exception). Furthermore, if I replace the space characters with underscores (as Ani Fichadia suggested), it does show them (also after the letter) even though I'm using string.length() and not string.length() + 1. :)

Comment: the problem is, i've traced this method in src code, and it just calls a native method ... so i think the native method that trims last space?!